# What is use case for forEach() loop?

Tags: dart

In almost every example on `forEach` you can find this:

```
List<String> footballplayers = ['Ronaldo', 'Messi', 'Neymar', 'Hazard'];
footballplayers.forEach((names) => print(names));
```

But there is a warning in IDE `Function literals should not be passed to 'forEach'.` and a suggestion `Try using a 'for' loop.`.

Then what is the use case for the `forEach`?

Comment: You can find the full explanation for this particular IDE warning here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal, the use case is to pass an existing function by name `footballplayers.forEach(print)`, rather than a function literal.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use forEach where you have a chain of functions like list.map(...).filter(...).forEach(...) Or if you already have a function that operates on an item like print.

cons:

- Slower than while and for loops
- Can not easily break in the middle of the loop (continue, break)
- Can not be awaited, you need to use Future.forEach

pros:

- cascade, ie: list..add(1)..where()..forEach()..map()